# Inside UITableView cell how to display the specified array data

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am new to Swift and I am trying to create Tableview in which I have only 3 Rows (Morning, Afternoon, and Night). If I click on the Morning row my cell must expand. It must display `keynumber` number of user whose  time 8 - 12. Same for Afternoon and Night.

I have specified array data of `User[]` in which `keynumber`, time and other data are there.

I tried to do with `if` condition in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` but it displays only one user key for the Morning row. It doesn't display another users key in that particular time limit.

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!
    var items: [String] = ["We", "Heart", "Swift"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
    }


    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.items.count;
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        var cell:UITableViewCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as UITableViewCell

        cell.textLabel?.text = self.items[indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) {
        print("You selected cell #\(indexPath.row)!")
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Have a try, works like a charm here

```
struct User {
   var keynumber: Int
   var time: NSData
}

class TableViewController: UITableViewController {

var userArr : Array<User> = [] //raw user data

var sortedUser : [String : Array<User>] = ["Morning": [], "Afternoon": [], "Night": []]
var sectionStatusArr : [String: Bool] = ["Morning": false, "Afternoon": false, "Night": false] // section status array used to control expanding

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //classify user into corresponding group(time zone)
    for _ in 0...19 {
        let randomKey = Int( arc4random()%23)
        let user = User(keynumber: randomKey, time: NSData())

        userArr.append(user)
    }

    //sort user: 8-12 -> morning, 13-18 -> afternoon, 19-8 -> night
    for user in userArr{
        switch user.keynumber {
        case 8,9,10,11,12:
            sortedUser["Morning"]?.append(user)
        case 13,14,15,16,17,18:
            sortedUser["Afternoon"]?.append(user)
        default:
            sortedUser["Night"]?.append(user)
        }
    }

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return sortedUser.keys.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows


    var rowcount = 0
    var shouldExpandSection = false
    switch section {
    case 0:
        rowcount = (sortedUser["Morning"]?.count)!
        shouldExpandSection = sectionStatusArr["Morning"]!
    case 1:
        rowcount = (sortedUser["Afternoon"]?.count)!
        shouldExpandSection = sectionStatusArr["Afternoon"]!
    default:
        rowcount = (sortedUser["Night"]?.count)!
        shouldExpandSection = sectionStatusArr["Night"]!
    }
    return shouldExpandSection ? rowcount : 0
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 40
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 60
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let header = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 375, height: 60))

    let nameBtn = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 375, height: 60))
    nameBtn.backgroundColor = UIColor.cyan
    nameBtn.tag = section
    nameBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.headerTouched(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)

    switch section {
    case 0:
        nameBtn.setTitle("Morning", for: .normal)
    case 1:
        nameBtn.setTitle("Afternoon", for: .normal)
    default:
        nameBtn.setTitle("Night", for: .normal)
    }

    header.addSubview(nameBtn)

    return header
}

func headerTouched(sender:UIButton){
    switch sender.tag {
    case 0:
        sectionStatusArr["Morning"] = !sectionStatusArr["Morning"]!
    case 1:
        sectionStatusArr["Afternoon"] = !sectionStatusArr["Afternoon"]!
    default:
        sectionStatusArr["Night"] = !sectionStatusArr["Night"]!
    }
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}


override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    var sectionArr : Array<User>= []
    switch indexPath.section {
    case 0:
        sectionArr = sortedUser["Morning"]!
    case 1:
        sectionArr = sortedUser["Afternoon"]!
    default:
        sectionArr = sortedUser["Night"]!
    }

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "reuseIdentifier", for: indexPath)

    for subview in cell.subviews{
        subview.removeFromSuperview()
    }

    let lab = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 375, height: 40))
    lab.text = "Un:" + String(sectionArr[indexPath.row].keynumber)
    lab.textAlignment = .center
    cell.addSubview(lab)

    return cell
}

}
```

Comment: How does this work : switch user.keynumber ?  Also I am getting error for  #selector(self.headerTouched(sender:))

Comment: That's a simple switch case usage. According to your classification rule: morning- [8:00 - 12:00) , afternoon - [12:00 - 18:00), night - [18:00 - 8:00). And what's your IDE, this code works in Xcode8 & Swift3.0. I shall attach entire project tomorrow once I back to work

Comment: Entire project could be download from [here](https://github.com/Millionaryearl/Stack-Overflow/tree/master/TableVC)

Comment: Thank you. I will try implementing this.